# How to load JSON data from asset folder into Recyclerview

Tags: android, json, sqlite, android-studio, android-recyclerview

i get stuck in my data in RecyclerView. I have a json in asset folder like this :

[image: json data]

I want to load this data into my RecyclerView and CardView. I have read many tutorials but there is none regarding my case. Every tutorial for RecyclerView always loads JSON from the internet.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, you are trying to do everything in 1 big step. You are rarely going to find the solution for your particular problem all in one place. Best way to approach problems is to divide them into smaller problems.
For example, if we take your problem, it can be divided into these parts:

1. Reading a file in asset folder
2. Parsing file data into json
3. Extract data from json
4. Use the data in adapter for recyclerview

Out of these 4 parts, you should already know the fourth part, so now you need to look for first 3 parts. 
If you google each part, you will find many answers to each part.

**1. Reading a file in asset folder**

Following function will give you file contents in *String*:

```
 private String getFileContentsAsString(Context context, String file)
    {
        String str = "";
        try
        {
            AssetManager assetManager = context.getAssets();
            InputStream in = null;
            try {
                in = assetManager.open(file);
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(in);
            char [] inputBuffer = new char[100];

            int charRead;
            while((charRead = isr.read(inputBuffer))>0)
            {
                String readString = String.copyValueOf(inputBuffer,0,charRead);
                str += readString;
            }
        }
        catch(IOException ioe)
        {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
        }

        return str;
    }
```

**2. Parsing file data into json**
Now that you have the data as string, you can parse it into JSON:

```
          String fileString = getFileContentsAsString("contents.json");
          JSONObject  json = new JSONObject(fileString);
```

**3. Extract data from json**
Get the json array and then *map* the data on to your own objects.

```
          JSONArray itemArray = json.getJSONArray("items");
```

**4. Use data in Adapter**
Use data from above steps to populate your adapter.

Again, resources for all these steps are already available out there.

Comment: thank you brother
I'm sorry
And I appreciate the misunderstanding required of me
you are right
I have to do the rest of the code

Comment: @amghawnbena please upvote and accept the answer if it was helpful.